# Rake task NoMethodError: undefined method `task' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake

I have this code which works fine (!!! without the first line "task..."!!!) in console. It creates events in DB. However no luck when running the rake (rake fetch_ttt):

```
task :fetch_ttt => :environment do
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'

    url = "http://www.example.com"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.css("#eventrow").each do |item|
        unless Event.find_by_name(item.at_css("a").text).present?
            Event.create(
                :start_time => item.at_css("#eventdate").text,
                :name => item.at_css("a").text,
                :url => item.at_css("a")[:href]
            )
        end
    end
end
```

This is the trace (not much in dry run neither):

```
** Invoke fetch_ttt (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) environment
** Execute (dry run) fetch_ttt
```

It has been fine couple hours ago. Since then I did a "bundle update", made some DB migrations, edited associations. I tried rolling back migrations and removed model association changes with no luck. I suspect the gems.

Below the 3 gems I rolled back to the previous versions to see if they are responsible but not. And the full diff.

old ones:

```
gem 'rake',           '10.5.0'
gem 'http',            '0.9.8'
gem 'ipaddress',        '0.8.2'
```

full diff:

```
-    bcrypt (3.1.10)
+    bcrypt (3.1.11)
-    carrierwave (0.10.0)
+    carrierwave (0.11.2)
+      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
-    concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
+    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
-    devise (3.5.6)
+    devise (4.1.1)
-      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
+      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
-      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
-    domain_name (0.5.20160128)
+    domain_name (0.5.20160310)
-    excon (0.45.4)
+    excon (0.49.0)
-      excon (~> 0.45)
+      excon (~> 0.49)
****lots of stuff related to "fog" gem
-    http (0.9.8)
+    http (0.9.9)
-    ipaddress (0.8.2)
+    ipaddress (0.8.3)
-    mime-types (2.99)
-    mini_magick (4.4.0)
+    mime-types (2.99.1)
+    mimemagic (0.3.1)
+    mini_magick (4.5.1)
     mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
-    minitest (5.8.4)
-    multi_json (1.11.2)
+    minitest (5.9.0)
+    multi_json (1.12.0)
-    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
+    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
-    responders (2.1.1)
+    responders (2.2.0)
-    sprockets (3.5.2)
+    sprockets (3.6.0)
-    sprockets-rails (3.0.1)
+    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
-    tilt (2.0.2)
+    tilt (2.0.4)
```

Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.1.4, I am on C9 IDE. But doesn't work on heroku neither.

**UPDATE**

reverted back to rake 10.5.0 (and did grep rake Gemfile.lock) now in the console I only get:

```
<Rake::Task fetch_ttt => [environment]>
```

scraping doesn't run at all :(

Comment: You might want to change `Event.create(` to `Event.create!(`. That would raise an exception when it is not possible to save the event. That error message might help you to identify the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like it is the first line. Pls see my reply to Jeffrey's comment below

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough info here to give a definitive answer, but I would start by investigating the root cause for why it isn't working on heroku.

For example, does the rake task run at all?  How do you know?

If so, do `heroku run rails c` and try doing the sequence of code yourself.  Inspect the database records before and after you expect a chance.   What happened?

If it didn't run, what type of output did you get?  `heroku logs` can also be helpful.

One other little tip, it's possible to use `byebug` with `heroku logs -t`.  Although I only recommend this in your staging environment and only if you're willing to clean up the git history afterwards.

In short, my answer is I would solve it by debugging more directly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see this in the heroku app logs:
2016-05-17T18:48:20.173330+00:00 heroku[run.1863]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake fetch_ttt`
2016-05-17T18:48:20.471600+00:00 heroku[run.1863]: State changed from starting to up
2016-05-17T18:48:25.987409+00:00 heroku[run.1863]: State changed from up to complete
2016-05-17T18:48:25.953054+00:00 heroku[run.1863]: Process exited with status 0
nothing gets saved to the DB

Comment: Right, so I would `heroku run rails c` to get an interactive prompt into your heroku rails environment and then I would try line by line running the code in question by hand to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: hmmmm.... I got: "NoMethodError: undefined method `task' for main:Object
        from (irb):2". Googling now

Comment: Which line of code is generating this error?  I don't see `task` variable referenced in your code.

Comment: It is this line: "task :fetch_ttt => :environment do" .

Comment: And the rake task runs locally for you without error?

Comment: I never used this exact first line locally ... Sorry! :) Just now. Modifying question now

Answer (score 0):

outcommented

```
#require 'nokogiri'
#require 'open-uri'
```

and now it works. Even with rake 11.1.2